# jQuery var wont save

Tags: jquery, wordpress, var

I have `a href="tel:0400000000` value that I am loading within the page (it's a php echo for the phone number). I am immediately changing the `href` via jQuery to hide it (`href=tel:hidden`) with the hope that when I run a specific action/function I can revert back to the original. It is in a wordpress plugin hence the format for the jQuery.

I have included the start of the jQuery function to assist in any responses.

***UPDATED***

**Original HTML**

```
<a class="button primary is-small expand" id="reunitePersonCall" href="tel:0400000000" ><span>Call Person</span></a>
```

**jQuery**

```
(function($){

    $(function() {
        
        $('#geoLocationButton').off().click(initiate_geolocation);
        
        $('#reunitePersonCall').data("saved", $('#reunitePersonCall').attr("href")).attr({
            "disabled":true,
            "href":"tel:hidden",
        }).prop("onclick", null);
        
        $('#reunitePersonNotify').attr("disabled", true);
        
        // Initiate Geolocation
        function initiate_geolocation() {

            navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(showPosition,showErrors,{timeout: 5000});
            
        }

        // Output Geolocation
        function showPosition(position){

            var longitude = position.coords.longitude;
            var latitude = position.coords.latitude;
            
            $.ajax({
                url:    plugin_locate_person_obj.ajaxurl,
                type:   'POST',
                data:   { 
                        action: 'plugin_locate_person_request',
                        longitude: position.coords.longitude,   // $_POST['longitude'];
                        latitude: position.coords.latitude      // $_POST['latitude'];
                        },
                
                success: function(data) {
                    $('#geoLocationButton').html("Location Recorded").attr("disabled", true);
                    $('#geoLocationMap').html('<iframe src="https://maps.google.com/maps?q=' + latitude + ',' + longitude + '&z=17&output=embed" width="100%" height="170" frameborder="0" style="border:0"></iframe>');
                    $('#reunitePersonNotify').attr("disabled", false).off().click(reunite_person);
                    $('#reunitePersonCall').attr("disabled", false).off().attr("href", $('#reunitePersonCall').data("saved")).click(reunite_person);
                }
                
            });

        }

        // Geolocation Errors
        function showErrors(error) {

            switch(error.code) {

                case error.PERMISSION_DENIED: alert("Location Denied by User.");
                break;

                case error.POSITION_UNAVAILABLE: alert("Location Could Not be Detected.");
                break;

                case error.TIMEOUT: alert("Location Request Timed Out.");
                break;

                default: alert("Unknown Error.");
                break;

            }

        }
                
        function reunite_person() {
            
            var jsDate      = new Date();
            var finder_date = jsDate.toLocaleDateString("en-AU");
            var finder_time = jsDate.toLocaleTimeString("en-AU");
            
            $.ajax({
                url:    plugin_reunite_person_obj.ajaxurl,
                type:   'POST',
                data:   { 
                        action: 'plugin_reunite_person_request',
                        finder_name: $('input[name=finder_name]').val(),
                        finder_phone: $('input[name=finder_phone]').val(),
                        finder_date: finder_date,
                        finder_time: finder_time
                        },
                
                success: function(data) {
                    $("#reunitePersonNotify").prop("onclick", null).off("click");
                    $("#reunitePersonCall").prop("onclick", null).off("click");
                    $('#reunitePersonResults').html(data);
                    $('#geoPrivacy').hide();
                    
                }
            
            });
            
        }

    });

})(jQuery);
```

What I am trying to achieve is the original html a href value (eg: tel: 0400000000) is "saved" in the var, then I can do what ever I want to the href attribute to then be able to revert it back to the original value (through the var).

When the page loads, because of the jquery, the button link is 'tel:hidden'. But when i click the button attached to `geoLocationButton`, the button associated to `reunitePersonCall` is then activated (no longer disabled). When I want to click that button it is a success, HOWEVER the `$('#reunitePersonCall').attr("disabled", false).off().attr("href", $('#reunitePersonCall').data("saved")).click(reunite_person);` doesn't seem to do what it is meant too (which is revert the a href back to the original `tel:0400000000` but it does perform the 'reunite_person' action).

Comment: What is the point of the tel:hidden? If you want to show and hide the number or grey it out, use .show()/.hide() or change the css

Comment: Because other information has to be entered before I want to release the phone number and I dont want to accessible via the source code. Thank you - you gave me another idea.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It looks like the `Phone` variable is not visible in the success function scope. You can either declare it globally, or even better, just save the phone number as an attribute of the `<a href>` tag:

```
// Save href in data-saved before updating attribs:
$('#Call').data("saved", $("#Call").attr("href")).attr({
  "disabled":true,
  "href":"tel:hidden",
})
```

Restore:

```
success: function(data) {
  $('#Call').attr("disabled", false).off().attr("href", $('#Call').data("saved"));
}
```

Comment: Thank-you for your prompt response. I ran console.log() under the var creation, and it has returned "tel:0400000000" "tel:hidden" so that var is still not saving.

Comment: @Aliqua I would have to see your exact code to understand why that is happening.

Comment: thanks so much for your input. I played in jsfiddle for a little bit, and separated the top line into two separate calls and now it works. shows blank on page load, then the success occurs and it repopulates the href with the saved data. you're a champion!

Answer (score 0):

I Tried the code, it worked for me.

Two options that I can think about are:

1. you are using the `var` keyword, which causes the variable to be local to that scope, and unknown in the ajax `success` call.
2. the `success` call is not executed, was it?

Also, never trust the `console.log()` function as to the content of variables, since it's not Synchronous

Comment: I also took the console out and checked the href at the bottom, and it wouldn't update. I will investigate if there are any other functions within my code that i haven't provided that might make my version not work.

Comment: Try to remove the `var` keyword.

Comment: I updated the question with the full jquery code so you can see exactly what happens and whether I have an error somewhere else. basically, the html has the `href="tel:0400000000"`, then the jquery needs to save that href value, replace it with `href="tel:hidden"`, and then when the button associated with `geoLocationButton` is clicked, the `reunitePersonCall` should replace the `href="tel:hidden"` with `href="tel:0400000000"`. If you can identify anything, could you please reply with a new answer?

Comment: just curious, but i did `var saved = $('#reunitePersonCall').data("saved", $('#reunitePersonCall').attr("href"));`, and console.log(saved) returned: `S.fn.init [a#reunitePersonCall.button.primary.is-small.expand]`

Comment: @Aliqua To extract the href, you should do: `var saved = $('#reunitePersonCall').data("saved", $('#reunitePersonCall').attr("href")).attr("href")`. But why are you saving it in a variable when this code is already saving it as a data attribute in the DOM? That is just redundant.

Comment: The var was just to call it from the console log. Will try that - thank you!

Comment: I thought the html href in question would be enough.. the entire script fires (sucess) and does what it meant to except for the reinstatement of the original href value.